# Detecting # of Core Data objects in motionEnded:?

Tags: uitableview, core-data, core-motion, alertview

I'm trying to detect the amount of objects I have in Core Data when the user shakes the device. When I try and call a NSFetchRequest inside of motionEnded:, the simulator crashes with an unknown error at main.

Is doing a fetch like this inside of motionEnded: possible?

The code I have so far:

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
        // see if we have albums to upload

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Groups" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

        NSUInteger group_count = [managedObjectContext countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

        if (group_count == 0)
        {
            // show alertview
        }
        else
        {
            // show another alertview
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. You can trigger a search and an alert view based on the search result triggered by a gesture, including a shake gesture.

Check what exactly your error is, so pass an error object to your `countForFetchRequest` method. Possibly your `managedObjectContext` is nil or you have some problem with your entity name. ("Groups" would be a bad name for an entity. "Group" is much more logical.)